# GROUP BY (a,b) and (b,a)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table like this :

```
player1    player2    player3    player4    score1    score2
   1          2          3          4         11         2  
   1          2          3          4          4         11
   2          1          3          4         11         5
```

If I query : `SELECT player1, player2, SUM(score1) FROM mytable GROUP BY player1, player2`

I will get :

```
player1   player2   SUM(score1)
   1         2          15
   2         1          11
```

However, I would like to `GROUP BY player1,player2 AND player2,player1` at the same time, to get :

```
player   player   SUM(score1)
   1         2         26
```

Does anyone know if it's possible (I use MySQL).

If it's not, do you know a good way to do it in PHP ?

Comment: Normalise your schema

Comment: @Strawberry Maybe my table isn't goo, yes. Do you think I should've group my players in another table and have something like : group1, group2, score1, score2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select least(player1, player2), greatest(player1, player2), sum(score1)
from mytable
group by least(player1, player2), greatest(player1, player2);
```

Comment: That's perfect, I don't know why i didn't think about it. :)

Comment: @Strawberry you can downvote for any reason you want, as long as you aren't targeting any user in particular (and you aren't). I'm curious about why you felt the need of leaving a comment before you do though

Comment: @Strawberry I see, sounds fine to me. Anyway, I think you should treat every downvote the same

Comment: @Strawberry Must every answer to a question regarding a sub-optimal design contain the caveat that the answer is a workaround to a design issue? It gets tedious to repeat over an over, and often when it's mentioned you learn that the OP is stuck with the design.

Comment: @HartCO Unfortunately, I think so, yes. The paradigm is that SO forms a canon of the best knowledge available on a variety of subjects. Here, the subject is the management of relational data. So proposing solutions that don't at least consider the possibility that the design is flawed cheat those that come here to learn about relational databases.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Your protestations would be much more credible if you answered more questions yourself.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Each time you downvote, you could provide an improved answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Answer (score -1):

or try this

```
select min(player1) as player1,max(player2) as player2, sum(score1) as score1 from
(
select player1, player2, SUM(score1) as score1 FROM mytable GROUP BY player1, player2
) as t
```